# Java heap space error with Spark running K means on EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I'm trying to run K-means with Spark on a sample document that is only 22MB and I am getting a Java Heap Space Error. Any thoughts? It fails on the clusters line.

Sample data and code are on my [github](https://github.com/ataipale/yelp_but_better/blob/master/k_means_spark.py)

```
# run in ipython spark shell, IPYTHON=1 pyspark

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.feature import HashingTF
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans, KMeansModel
from numpy import array
from math import sqrt
import json
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row


sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sample = sqlContext.read.json("/home/ubuntu/yelp_project/sample.json")
sample.registerTempTable("sample")
reviews = sample.map(lambda x: Row(name= x[1], reviews=' '.join((a[3] for a in       x[0])))) 


hashingTF = HashingTF()
tf = hashingTF.transform(reviews.map(lambda x: x.reviews))
clusters = KMeans.train(tf, 2, maxIterations=10, runs=10, initializationMode="random")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my documents were very large and the number of features was too large to be stored in memory allocated for the spark process. To solve the problem, I initialized my HashingTF with a max number of features:

```
hashingTF = HashingTF(5000)
```